# Setting a type for an object property using dot notation, only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript, trying to define and assign an "Item" type to an object that's a child of another object.

This works:

```
interface Item {
    name: string
}
var bar: Item = {
    name: 'name',
};
```

This errors:

```
interface foo {}
var foo:foo = {};
interface foo {
    bar?: {}
}
interface Item {
    name: string
}
foo.bar:Item = {
    name: 'name',
}
```

Why?

```
'Item' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

How can I assign a type to foo.bar?

Edit:

Based on heyitsjhu's answer,

```
interface foo {}
var foo:foo = {};
interface foo {
    bar?: {}
}
interface Item {
    name: string
}
foo.bar = {
    name: 'name',
} as Item
```

This works as expected, is there a way to put the "as Item" part next to the `foo.bar =` for readability? Or am I stuck with setting the type at the very end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to say `foo.bar` is an `Item`? I think you can cast it as such:

```
interface Item {
  name: string
}

foo.bar = {
    name: 'name',
} as Item
```

If not, then you might want to assign foo an actual interface or type that defines what bar is expected to be.

```
interface Item {
    name: string
}

interface Foo {
    bar: Item
}

let foo: Foo = {
    bar: {
       name: 'name'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a notation to put the 'as Item' on the line where the `foo.bar =` is for readability?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. TS has a section on Type Assertions and as far as I can tell, this approach always asserts the type at the end. I agree it's not the most readable but after you get used to it, it becomes familiar. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions

Answer (score 2):

The type for the bar prop would need to be defined within the type definition for foo (Foo).

So:

```
type Foo: {
  bar: Item;
}

const foo: Foo = {
  bar: {
    name: "his name"
  }
}
```